# How can I create new dataframe column with values based on condition of 2 columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, one containing 2 columns (date and key) and other containing the same 2 columns (date and key). I would like to create a new column in one dataframe with '1' value if the date and the key exists in the other dataframe, and '0' if it does not exist. Here is an example:

```
df1:
+---------+--------+
|  date   |  key   |
+---------+--------+
|  date1  |    A   |
+---------+--------+
|  date2  |    A   |
+---------+--------+
|  date3  |    B   |
+---------+--------+


df2:
+---------+--------+
|  date   |  key   |
+---------+--------+
|  date1  |    A   |
+---------+--------+
|  date4  |    C   |
+---------+--------+
|  date5  |    B   |
+---------+--------+


resulting df1:

+---------+--------+--------+
|  date   |  key   |  col3  |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  date1  |    A   |   1    |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  date2  |    A   |   0    |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  date3  |    B   |   0    |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

In this example, as the first row of df1 (date1, A) exists in df2, the value of col3 is 1, and the other rows are 0.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `indicator` parameter for new columns and then convert to `1,0` by compare `both` string:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='col3', on=['date','key'])
df['col3'] = df['col3'].eq('both').astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col3'].eq('both'), 1, 0)
```

Comment: @MustafaAydın - Thank you, I think `isin` is cannot used here, because it compare by rows, so first row in df1 with first row in df2..., also failed if different numebr of rows.

Comment: Actually for each row, it looks if it exists in the whole data frame, not only the corresponding row. Also, works if different number of rows. However, the index should be exactly the same so even though the values are the same it won't work. So it is not suitable I agree.